# Default value on Django Models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-1.8

I'm working on the following model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Page of XXXX')
```

I'm trying to set a **default value for the page field that contains the username**. Something like: 'Page of Will' or 'Page of Sam', where the users were Will or Sam.

Thanks,
P.Arias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using with your "create()" function:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    page = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name):
        if name:
            return Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=name, 
                                                 page='Page of ' + name)
            # or
            return cls(user=name, page='Page of ' + name).save()
```

And insert users through this function:

```
Profile.create(name="Will")
```